# Get Font File by it's Font Name Using font_manager in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, fonts

I have the script below to populate a combobox with a list of system fonts:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.font_manager as fontman
print([f.name for f in fontman.fontManager.ttflist]) #get the list of font names
```

How can I get the font file by the font name? Keep in mind that font file and font name can be different.

Answer (score 0):

A font file name is completely independent of the name of the font it contains.